# Google Tasks Shared List Limit?

Tags: google-tasks

I am admin to a Google Business account. I have 12 users in the account. Some of my users are able to have 3+ lists shared, but others are getting prompts that they need to have "Premium" in order to be able to have more shared lists whenever they try to add a third list. Why is this only being prompted for some of the users, while the others can have 4 or 5 shared lists?

Comment: It would be better if you raise this issue further to the Workspace support 
at https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213, given that the affected user accounts are business accounts.

Comment: I did, and I was told they did not have the tools to be able to assist.